# Laravel datetime incorrect format when saving to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, datetime

I'm working on a project running on an existing database. The problem is that datetime columns are inserted using a wrong format in SQL Server. The server uses datetime as Y-m-d and data is being saved as Y-d-m.

I've made some tests, and when saving to MariaDB datetime is saved properly.

There are custom fields for updated_at and created_at, so they are declared on the model.

**In the model**

```
class NotaFaturamento extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'DT_CADASTRO';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'DT_ATUALIZACAO';
```

This is the QueryLog print after saving data. As you can see in the query log, datetime format is correctly parsed to SQL Server.

[Querylog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gxKF.png)

**On Config\app.php**

```
'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
'locale' => 'pt-BR',
```

Is this something that needs to be configured on SQLServer? I've searched a lot about this, but most of the responses are regarding SQL Server separators.

I also declared protected `$dateFormat = 'Y-m-j h:i:s:000A';` on the model but the same problem happens. The issue is also present when storing Carbon objects.

Regards.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Dan, the issue could be the DATEFORMAT on the SQL Server being used as DMY. Also, as pointed [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502980/how-format-datetime-for-sql-server-in-laravel) and answered by @dns_nx, there is a workaround to manually change dateformat for saving on SQL Server.

I've added to my model

```
public function getDateFormat()
{
   return 'Y-d-m H:i:s.v';
}
```

And any other date attributes on the model should be declared as being date:

```
protected $dates = ['DT_EMISSAO', 'DT_COMPETENCIA'];
```

I don't think this is the proper way to solve the issue, but it does work. And you could create another basemodel as mentioned by @dns_nx.

Regards

Comment: Datetime columns are an internal binary format in SQL Server. The formatted string you see when querying the data is formatted by the client application.

Comment: OK, I understand that, but since laravell/eloquent has the save() method built in it's system, shouldn't it make the proper conversions when saving to sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to Laravel/Eloquent specifically but a parameterized query with a strongly-typed `datetime` parameter will save the value properly. Since the value is not being saved correctly, it is because:

1) The actual parameter value provided for a `datetime` parameter type is wrong

2) The parameter type is (n)varchar with the value passed as a string that doesn't conform to ISO 8601 format

3) The parameter is passed as a string literal that doesn't conform to ISO 8601 format

For troubleshooting, run a SQL Trace (Extended Events or Profiler) on your dev database instance including `batch_completed` and `rpc_completed` events to capture the actual SQL queries. This will identify which of the above causes is the culprit. The `rpc_completed` will include both the parameter type and value. Be aware that with a datetime parameter type, the trace will always display the datetime value in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fff` format, which is just a rendering of the actual binary value passed.

If the parameter type is `(n)varchar`, the non-ISO 8601 datetime string '2018-10-06 09:07:07.222' will be parsed by SQL Server using the current session `DATEFORMAT` setting. The default `DATEFORMAT` for a Portuguese language login is `DMY` but can be overridden by an explict SET `DATEFORMAT` command previously executed on the same session. With `DATEFORMAT DMY` and the string value '2018-10-06 09:07:07.222', the month and day portion will be parsed as month 6 day 10. Datetime literals are similarly parsed.

A quick search turned up [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18991). Consequently, if you can't coerce a strongly-typed `datetime` to be passed by the application, a workaround may be to use [`datetime2(3)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) instead of `datetime`. SQL Server will parse `datetime2` string '2018-10-06 09:07:07.222' as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fff` regardless of the session `DATEFORMAT` setting. I recommend `datetime2` for new development since it won't round the fraction seconds to 1/300 units and store greater precision values in less space.

Comment: Thanks for the info Dan. I've traced the Query and both created_at and updated_at fields were being parsed as ISO, but as you mentioned the DATEFORMAT for the database is set to DMY.